# Local C pointer variable

Tags: scope, local, heap-memory, stack-memory

Suppose i define the following code:

```
int *func()
{
    int *p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // memory is allocated from heap
                                      // which can be accessed anytime.

    return p;    // but we created p which has a local scope and vanishes as
                 //soon as function exits.  
}
```

Then how does this thing work? p being a local varible (a pointer holding a address to 
the dynamic memory). I mean the memory itself from HEAP should definitely continue to exist, but the pointer variable has a local scope. How come i will be able to get this pointer?

Comment: btw `(*int) func()` should be `int *func()` the same goes for `(*int)` it should be `(int *)` as for ur other question, its cause ur returning a copy of the memory address returned from `malloc` not `&p` that would be   returning the address of p which would have being deallocated.

Comment: @samy.vilar I have corrected.

Comment: @GreatCoder depending on the architecture this example would not be more efficient, depending on the sizeof(pointer) 32 bit will have 4 bytes , 64 will have 8 bytes, most likely your integer will have the same size as the pointers

Comment: @OliverStutz Right now I am mainly concerned with the concept of scope of the varibles/pointers. You may be very right with the efficiency concept

Comment: @OliverStutz Can u please elaborate on the size which u mentioned? I am not able to get it?

Comment: @GreatCoder try to do sizeof(pInt) and sizeof(int) after that print both of them, you will see that if both are of the same size it is not worth returning a pointer of it, the size given back here is in bytes so 64 -> 8 bytes, 32 -> 4 bytes. Here the code is use, you should include iostream if you haven't:  int * p = new int(200); std::cout << sizeof(p) << std::endl;
 cout << sizeof(*p) << endl;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is simply a pointer which refers to the memory block that you've allocated.

The lifetime of the *allocated block* extends beyond the end of the function.

It's true that the actual *pointer* will go out of scope on return but you've already returned a copy of it it to the caller before then.

> And, as an aside, you probably meant `int*` (in both cases) rather than `*int` and `(*int)`. In any event, you don't want to explicitly cast the return value from `malloc` in C - it can hide subtle errors. C is perfectly capable of converting the `void *` returned by `malloc` into any suitable pointer type.

It would be better written as something like:

```
int *func (void) {
    int *p = malloc (sizeof (int));
    return p;
}
```

You'll also notice the use of `void` in the function to explicitly state the function takes no parameters. That's preferable to just having `()` which is subtly different (an *indeterminate* number of parameters).

Comment: What is bad in conveting/typecasting the void pointer to int type explicitly?

Comment: In systems where an int and a void pointer are different sizes, and you forget to include the header for malloc, you'll run into problems because the assumed return value of a function is an int.

Answer (score 2):

Finally after understanding... I was able to get the concept.

1. When we return the pointer p... definitely p, which was allocated
   on stack vanishes.
2. Since values are returned with a call by value mechanism and p was holding an address
   of memory allocated on the heap. That address is still valid and holds reference  to a valid memory location.
3. Thus p itself vanishes, but the value returned by it is copied to a variable in the calling function and hence this justifies the correctness of the code.